# PDO and PDOStatement, magical assignments

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following "test-class" made on the fly:
http://sumoin.pastebin.com/ff744ea4
No fine-tuning or something else, just a brief testing pdo class.

And I have the test.php:
http://sumoin.pastebin.com/d70dcb4ec

The funny thing is:

The PDOStatement object is never returned directly and I it never gets assigned to `$this->handler->stmt`

but the executing `$stmt->execute()` works as fine as if everything is okey.
But if I use `$this->handler->stmt->someMethod` I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   bindParam() on a non-object

(bindParam is just an example)

I already checked the query, and it has no mistakes in it, I tried to use "bindValue()", did not work.
I tried to use integers instead of ':name' to assign values to parameters.
I ran the pure query through the `$this->handler->query()` and it worked.

Where is the problem located?
I do not want to assign my PDOStatement object while the runtime, I want it to be part of the class, when the "->prepare()" method is called.

Any ideas?
Please don't hit me if there is a duplicate out there, but I did not found anything that helped me.

> Information:
>
> - PHP5.2
> - PDO Extensions etc. installed
> - Apache2
> - MySQL5.1 (matching to the PDO version)

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to use a reference '$this->stmt =& $this->handler->prepare()'.
Still causes the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround/Solution:

```
public function prepare($query)
{
    return $this->handler->prepare($query);

    //$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // standard
    //return $this->stmt;
}

public function getStatement($query)
{
    $this->stmt = $this->prepare($query);
}
```

Comment: This works, however, I do not know why, but after a brainstrom while sitting on the toilette/wc I got this idea ;)